# Having issue with 'Null pointer access' in Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
if(key == '1'){//insert at ->right.right
    BinaryNode tempPointer = root;

    while(tempPointer != null){
        tempPointer = tempPointer.right;
    }
    BinaryNode newNode = new BinaryNode(x);
    newNode.right = null;
    newNode.left = null;
    size++;
    lastNode = newNode;
    newNode.parent = tempPointer;
    tempPointer.right = newNode;
}
```

It keeps saying `termPointer` can only be null at this location. I can't figure out why though.

This also fails:

```
newNode.parent = tempPointer.parent; //'tempPointer can only be null here'
tempPointer = newNode;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your while loop will only end when tempPointer is `null`. You don't set `tempPointer` to any other value after the loop, so it will stay `null` until the end of the function.

Answer (score 2):

You actually want a look ahead pointer that peeps to the right of the current node. Something like,

```
BinaryNode tempPointer = root;
lookaheadPointer = root;
while(lookaheadPointer != null) {
  tempPointer = lookaheadPointer;
  lookaheadPointer = tempPointer.right;
}
```

In your current code, the tempPointer is null at the end of the loop, as pointed out by @Julien